# how can I use jquery selected object outside the scope?

Tags: jquery

```
/* get every click event on input tags and send it to foo */
$('input').click( function() {
   foo($(this));
});

function foo(obj) {
/* do something with obj.. */
}
```

with above code, I will have an input object passed into function `foo` as an argument `obj`.
How should I use `obj`? do I need to re-run selector, like `$(obj)` to use all jquery-specific methods?

some more question : answers say that I have no need to wrap `obj` with $() again. what will happen if I re-wrap `obj` with `$(obj)`? (suppose function `foo` can take both jquery-selected objects and non-jquery-selected objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the jQuery object, so no need to wrap `$()` again.

Did you try running a jQuery function inside the `foo` function?

```
$('input').click( function() {
   foo($(this));
});

function foo(obj) {
   console.log(obj.val()); //should print the value in the console.
}
```

> some more question : answers say that I have no need to wrap obj with $() again. what will happen if I re-wrap obj with $(obj)? (suppose function foo can take both jquery-selected objects and non-jquery-selected objects)

You can simply do `obj[0]` to get the original `this` object.

Comment: Correct. Wrapping a jQuery object with the `$()` selector will do no harm. If you were writing a plugin that could take either object type it would be a good idea to wrap it with the jQuery selector.

Comment: @thkang It should not cause any hard.

Answer (score 1):

No.  If it's a jQuery object then you can use jQuery methods without referring to it with $ again.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are passing a jQuery object already so no need to re-wrap. But since jQuery event handlers assigns the element as `this` in the callback, you can write it cleaner like this:

```
$('input').click(foo);

function foo() {
    /* do something with this.. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can just use the object again from its reference, no need to re-select.